# Could not load GCS dataset into my Colab Tensorflow ipynb

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-storage

I just started to learn Tensorflow using Google Colab, but I am facing problems immediately...

I want to load an existing personal dataset already stored in Google Cloud Storage:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
!gsutil ls gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/
```

(where MY_BUCKET_NAME is actually "cloud-ai-platform-d7863b94-84f9..."). This lists out a few folders such as "MyDataSet_normal", ""MyDataSet_bad" in that bucket, which means my notebook is able to read this GCS bucket.

Then I followed https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/gcs to try loading the dataset:
`ds_train, ds_test = tfds.load(name="MyDataSet_normal", split=["train", "test"], data_dir="gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME", try_gcs=True)`, but it returned:

> DatasetNotFoundError: Dataset MyDataSet_normal not found.
> Available datasets:
> - abstract_reasoning
> - accentdb
> - aeslc
> - ...

Looks like it is trying to find "MyDataSet_normal" in the publicly shared *tensorflow_datasets*, not my own dataset in MY_BUCKET_NAME. I tried Google around, did not result in any helpful information.

What do I miss here? How can I tell my Colab notebook, please look into MY_BUCKET_NAME for the dataset, instead of the public *tensorflow_datasets*?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this [github link](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/2035)?

Comment: Thanks @RoopaM, do you mean we can not **stream** the existing dataset, must follow the link you provided, **download** a **copy** of it, then do everything on the downloaded **copy**?

Answer (score 0):

I had tried Google Cloud you can specific path but my trails period expired then I use Google Drive which is free.

You can use model.save or symmetric method, I stored them in a database buffer but the results and saved of it weights can remain untouched in a secured drive. There are many features on Google cloud and Google Collab but for dataset storage, Google Drive is enough except for filters.

Sample: Long terminal distance can save costs of reminders.

```
import io
import os
from os.path import exists

from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import client, file, tools
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
n_folder = 50
encoding = "utf-8"
    
# define path variables
credentials_file_path = 'F:\\temp\\Python\\credentials\\credentials.json'
clientsecret_file_path = 'F:\\temp\\Python\\credentials\\client_secret_183167298301-pfhgtdf6k8r4918csmftemgk00ln8l4r.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'

# define API scope
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

# define store
store = file.Storage(credentials_file_path)
credentials = store.get()
# get access token
if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(clientsecret_file_path, SCOPE)
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    
# define API service
http = credentials.authorize(Http())
drive = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Fuctions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def download_file( file_id, filename, filetype ): 
    print( 'downfile: ' + filename + ': ' + filetype )

    request = drive.files().get_media( fileId=file_id )
    file = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload( file, request )
    done = False

    if filetype == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder":
        return


    try:
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print( F'Download {int(status.progress() * 100)}.' )
        
    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        file = None
    
    tf.io.write_file(
        filename, file.getvalue(), name='write_file'
    )

    return 

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Write result to file
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
file = 'F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy\\01.tif'
image = tf.io.read_file( file )
image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
image = tf.image.resize(image, [8,8], method='nearest')

filename='F:\\temp\\datasets\\9.tif'

with open( filename, "wb" ) as f:
    b = bytes(str(image), encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(b)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Read result to file
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
temp = tf.io.read_file(
    filename, name='dataset_9'
)
temp = tf.io.decode_raw(
    temp, tf.uint8, little_endian=True, fixed_length=None, name=None
)
temp = tf.constant(temp, shape=(1, 8, 8, 3))
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[133 141 126 255]
  [ 94 107  90 255]
  [106 125  97 255]
  [141 140 122 255]
  [ 96 114  90 255]
  [ 88 106  82 255]
  [112 141  93 255]
  [116 127 111 255]]

 ...

 [[150 122 111 255]
  [180 152 141 255]
  [192 160 145 255]
  [185 153 138 255]
  [168 148 139 255]
  [189 158 138 255]
  [166 136 110 255]
  [ 68  83  64 255]]], shape=(8, 8, 4), dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean there is no way to use the dataset in GCS, you must download it first? In your code I do not see how you are accessing the dataset in your Google Drive, the ```download_file``` is not called by any statement.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I am missing something, but from your code, I see you are basically accessing some files from your local ```file = 'F:\\datasets\\...``` and ```filename='F:\\temp\\datasets\\9.tif' ```, so it is not reading from GCS or Google Drive directly, am I right?